# Get http variable JSF

Tags: java, http, jsf

I have a question about JSF and GET http request.

How can I get a GET variable in bean managed by JSF ?

I tried to use it but nothing is in the map.

> FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this will help you,

```
Map requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String para1 = (String) requestMap.get("para1");
```