# Using get http variables with JSF and good practices

Tags: jsf

1) Is it a good practice to use get http variable in JSF? it seems that it tries to avoid that.

2) Here is what I want to do: on the first page, I have a list of links, if you click on a link, you have a page with other links etc. like a tree.
I would like the user to be able to access the 3rd depth (for example) without starting from the top level (via a link with the related object ID in a get variable for instance).

so my question is:
How to set a get http variable from the managed bean?

To get it, this post is quite clear : [Get http variable JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339735/get-http-variable-jsf)

3) Of course, if you have another solution, feel free to share it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no means of a good/bad practice as to using GET requests in JSF. If the business requirement mandates using a GET request, then just use it. However, there's some history: in JSF 1.x there was no facility which eases applying/converting/validating GET parameters. You'd have to do it all yourself by traversing the `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` and/or by setting managed properties with `#{param}` and write all the conversion/validation boilerplate yourself. Using POST was then much easier (read: less code) and this might have caused the myth that GET is "bad" in JSF.

Since JSF 2.0, the new `<f:viewParam>` tag was introduced which should make it all a breeze. It's like the `<h:inputText>`, including conversion/validation, but then for request parameters.

Note that it's *actually* a bad practice to use POST for pure page-to-page navigation, which was more than often done in JSF 1.x. It resulted in non-bookmarkable and non-SEO-friendly requests.

#### See also

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)

Comment: Thanks!
Those posts are perfect! It's difficult to find the right post with "get variable" as keyword.

Comment: Most of those posts can be found in [our JSF wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) (you can get there by hovering the `[jsf]` tag below the question and then clicking the *info* link in that black popbox). Also, you can get the most interesting answers/practices/etc when you browse [the "FAQ" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf?sort=faq) of the `[jsf]` tag (the default is "Active" tab)